# Rails 3 - dumping PostgreSQL database into schema.rb has incorrect precision for numeric types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-postgresql

I have an existing postgresql database that I want to use in a new rails app, so I first want to dump the existing schema into schema.rb using `rake db:schema:dump`. However, when I do this, the schema.rb has a strange precision value for the numeric columns.

```
create_table "order", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    ....
    t.decimal  "Quantity",               :precision => 131089, :scale => 0
    ....
```

In my PostgreSQL db, the numeric type column does not have an explicit precision or scale set.

Is there a reason why precision is showing such a huge value?

I've also tried changing and removing the precision modifier in schema.rb, but everytime I do a migration, it regenerates the schema.rb file with these huge values. I've looked at the [ActiveRecord table definition](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html), but that wasn't very helpful.

Comment: What does `\d order` say from inside `psql`?

Comment: @mu-is-too-short: The type for Quantity shows up as "numeric"

Comment: Anything else in the table? What does `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.columns('order')` have to say from the Rails console?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is being picked as the maximum precision of a numeric value in PostgreSQL.  See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-numeric.html.